# TNB frame at every point along a curve

Tags: plotting, frame

How to plot a TNB frame at every point along a curve in Mathematica? That is,

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slightly modifying the first example in [`FrenetSerretSystem >> Neat Examples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrenetSerretSystem.html):

```
knot = KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"];
basis = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[knot[t], t]] // Simplify;

{tangent, normal, binormal} = Map[Arrow[{knot[t], knot[t] + #}] &, basis];

Show[ParametricPlot3D[knot[s], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
 Graphics3D[Table[{Thick, Blue, tangent, Red, normal, Green, binormal}, {t, 
    Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 50]}]], PlotRange -> 3]
```

[image]