# How can I draw a vector field on a curve?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

For didactic purposes (a line integral of a vector field) I'd like to plot a vector field along a curve in 2D and 3D, like in this picture:

[image]

Mathematica is able to vizualize [vector fields](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VectorVisualization.html).

Here is my unsuccessful attempt

```
VectorPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1]]
```

[image]

I know [this](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VectorFieldActingOnACurve/) and [this](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IntegratingAVectorFieldAlongACurve/) application to this end,
but those are not it. An analog of the [`PlotPositionVector`](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/AddOns/view.aspx?path=Student/VectorCalculus/PlotPositionVector&term=PlotPositionVector) command of Maple is required.

Comment: for 3D see [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/242173/125)

Comment: @kglr: I need not `TNB`, but a field plot along a curve, not along a knot. Thank you anyway.

Comment: `field[{x_, y_}] = {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}; 
Show[VectorPlot[Evaluate[field[{x, y}]], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   VectorScaling -> True, 
   VectorPoints -> Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi], .1}]], 
  Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]], AspectRatio -> Automatic] /.   
 Arrow[{{x_, y_}, {z_, w_}}] :> 
  Arrow[{{(x + z)/2, (y + w)/2}, {z, w}}]`

Comment: `field[{x_, y_}] = {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}; Show[
 VectorPlot[Evaluate[field[{x, y}]], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   VectorScaling -> True, 
   VectorPoints -> 
    Table[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi], .1}]] /.   
  Arrow[{{x_, y_}, {z_, w_}}] :> 
   Arrow[{{(x + z)/2, (y + w)/2}, {z, w}}], 
 ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Comment: @cvgmt: Thank you. Can you present this as an answer, adding 3d case? TIA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
vf[{x_, y_}] = {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2};

curve[t_] := Sqrt[t] {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
```

Using `ParametricPlot`:

```
scale = .2;

ParametricPlot[curve[t], {t, 0, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Thick, 
      Arrow[{curve @ #, curve @ # + (scale Norm[#] Normalize[#] & @ vf[curve@#])}] & /@ 
        Rest[Subdivide[0, 3 Pi, 50]]}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}]
```

[image]

Using `VectorPlot`:

```
VectorPlot[Evaluate @ vf[{x, y}], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
   VectorSizes -> {0, .5}, VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow", "Start"], 
 VectorPoints -> (curve /@ Subdivide[0, 3 Pi, 60]), 
 Epilog -> {Red, First@ParametricPlot[curve[t], {t, 0, 3 Pi}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {-5, 5}]
```

[image]

`ParametricPlot3D`:

```
vf3D[{x_, y_, z_}] = {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2, Sqrt[z] };
curve3D[t_] := Sqrt[t] {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/5};

Show[ParametricPlot3D[curve3D[t], {t, 0, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
  Graphics3D @ {Red, Thick, 
      Arrow[{curve3D @ #, curve3D @ # + (scale Norm[#] Normalize[#] &@
        vf3D[curve3D@ #])}] & /@ Rest[Subdivide[0, 3 Pi, 50]]}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. As usually, your answer is very well. However, I will be waiting some time for other answers.

Answer (score 8):

**Edition**

```
r[u_] = {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10};
curve = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}];
Show[VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   VectorScaling -> True, VectorMarkers -> "Arrow", 
   VectorPoints -> Table[r[u], {u, 0, 20, .1}]] /. 
  Arrow[{p1_, p2_}] :> Arrow[{(p1 + p2)/2, p2}], curve]
```

[image]

Or use the approach `Placed["Arrow", "Start"]` by @kglr

```
r[u_] = {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10};
curve = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}];
Show[VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  VectorScaling -> True, VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow", "Start"], 
  VectorPoints -> Table[r[u], {u, 0, 20, .1}]], curve]
```

[image]

```
r[u_] = {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10};
curve = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}];
vectorfield = 
  VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
    VectorScaling -> True, 
    VectorPoints -> Table[r[u], {u, 0, 20, .1}]] /. 
   Arrow[Tube[{p1_, p2_}, t_]] :> Arrow[Tube[{(p1 + p2)/2, p2}, t]];
Show[vectorfield, curve, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: cvgmt (@ does not work.):+1. Arrows are not nice for me.

Comment: `VectorMarkers -> 
 Placed["Arrow", 
  "Start"], VectorStyle -> Red, VectorColorFunction -> None`

Answer (score 6):

A 2D example:

```
field[{x_, y_}] = {-y^2, x  y};
curve[t_] = {t, t^3} + 0.3;
Show[
 ParametricPlot[curve[t], {t, -1 , 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{Automatic, 1}}], Table[Arrow[{curve[t], curve[t] + field[curve[t]]}], {t, -1, 1, .1}]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

And a 3D example:

```
field[{x_, y_, z_}] = 0.5 {-y^2, x  y, Sqrt[z y]};
curve[t_] = {t, t^3, Sqrt[t]};
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[curve[t], {t, 0 , 1},  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1.5}, {0, 2}}],
 Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Table[Arrow[{curve[t], curve[t] + field[curve[t]]}], {t, 0,  1, .05}]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: DanielHuber (@ does not work.) :+1. Your answer does not intersect with the kglr's one.

Comment: kgr extended his answer after the above comment of me.